# How to install Nomtimatim in postgresql (windows)

Tags: windows, postgresql, postgis

I am trying to do geocoding in the postgresql, and I have already installed TIGER geocoder successfully. Then, I want to use Nomtimatim in postgresql. However,since the installed guide (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation) does not provide any information for Windows. Is there any way to use Nominatim in postgresql on Windows?

I also tried the web API (outside database), but this way is easy to crash.

Thanks!

Comment: I downloaded the sources and took a quick look. I don't see any signs that it supports Windows - there's no Visual Studio project file or NMake makfile(s), the sources don't have any `#ifdef`s testing the `WIN32` macro, etc. I'd say the answer is "you don't".

Comment: Thanks for providing an criterion to judge whether one source can support Windows.